# I did not understand this question based on ratios

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

Rs. 535 is divided among A, B and C so that if Rs. 15, Rs 10, Rs 30 be subtracted from their respective shares, the remainders would have been in ratio 4:5:7. What was their initial shares

Comment: Can you write down some equations?

Comment: Tell us asap. $ $

Comment: The answer for solving such a system of equations would x = 135, y = 160 and Z = 240

Comment: x, y, z are A,B,C in your problem

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
A-15 &= 4x\\[4pt]
B-10 &= 5x\\[4pt]
C-30 &= 7x
\end{align*}
Add the equations.

But you know the value of $A+B+C$, hence you can solve for $x$.

Once you have $x$, plug it back into the equations to find $A,B,C$.